# Quick PlayFramework / Groovy

Tags: templates, groovy, playframework

Why does the following code always emit 'yes' (in HTML) even when `sel` has a different value other than 'audio'? (I've logged the values of `sel` and confirmed different values.)

This is my day 1 on Play. So, I may be doing something really stupid.

```
${sel='audio'?'yes':'no'}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know the Groovy templates that well, but I think it should be like this:

```
${sel=='audio'?'yes':'no'}
```

Your code:

```
${sel='audio'?'yes':'no'}
```

means; if 'audio' (a string that is not null will always be "true") then sel = 'yes' otherwise 'no', so it will never be 'no'.

Comment: not according to Groovy Ref http://groovy.codehaus.org/Operators#Operators-ElvisOperator%28%3F%3A%29

Comment: is right, you need == for the ternary to evaluate both sides of the expression; otherwise the left side of ternary will always be returned.

Comment: @roshan I think you are misreading the groovy example on the linked page. It is checking a boolean, and storing either 'male' or 'female' in a new variable. In your example, you want to compare a variable with a string and the result will be outputted. Therefore you need `==` for a comparison.

Comment: I think Jonas is right. As I understand it, the Elvis operator evaluates an expression and returns something if false or null, and something different otherwise. In this case the expression being evaluated is an assignment, which in turn evaluates to the value being assigned (in this case 'audio', which is not false nor null). You should use the == ('equals') operator.

Comment: Thanks Guys! Yes it was ==. Initially, by intuition I had == and it didn't work (may be I had some other error) and then I made the 'mistake' of checking the Groovy Ref and mis-interpreted their example :-)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at the yesNo extension: http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.1/javaextensions#yesNo